# Union in EF Core is not working for two lists

Tags: entity-framework, union

Union in EF Core is not working for two lists. I am getting the error,
"this overload of the method 'system.linq.tolist' is currently not supported." when joining two lists.

```
p.List1
.Select(q => new Dto1
{
     Id= q.Id,
     Name= q.Name
}).ToList()
.Union(List2.Select(obj => new Dto1
{
     Id= q.Id,
     Name= q.Name
}).ToList()
```

Comment: Can't help without defining "not working".

Comment: I've modified the description. Getting error when joining two lists.

Comment: The code isn't complete. At least one parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 0):

**You must assign Union result to your List or Create another one List and assign to it**

```
        var result = p.List1
        .Select(q => new Dto1
        {
            Id = q.Id,
            Name = q.Name
        }).ToList();

        result = result.Union(List2.Select(q => new Dto1
        {
            Id = q.Id,
            Name = q.Name
        }).ToList()).ToList();
```

> for more about Linq Union, Intersect, Intersect and Distinct  [learn here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/use-of-unionintersect-and-except-in-linq/)